# Juice problem combinations

Tags: probability, combinations

I have no idea how to start this question... It's impossible in my mind. Help please

The owner of a convenience store reports that 500 people who bought bottled fruit juice in a recent week.

400 people bought orange juice
110 bought Apple
50 bought grape
75 bought orange and apple
25 bought orange and grape
30 bought Apple and grape
15 bought orange Apple and grape

A.)How many people bought grape and orange but not Apple?

B.)How many buyers bought juice other than Apple orange or grape?

Comment: This question is A MESS. Please fix it!

Comment: Sorry! Fixed it

Comment: Given that "Apple" is capitalized, were those iPhones or Macs?

Comment: Not fixed enough IMO. How about a separate line for each statement (or at least commas in between them)? C'mon, show some minimal amount of effort if you're expecting others to make effort for you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be the set of people you bought orange juice.

Let $A$ be the set of people you bought apple juice.

Let $G$ be the set of people you bought grape juice.

Based on the information given, we know the following:

$|O|=400$.

$|A|=110$.

$|G|=50$.

$|O\cap A|=75$.

$|O\cap G|=25$.

$|A\cap G|=30$.

$|O\cap A\cap G|=15$.

For A), the number of people that bought orange and grape but not apple is $|O\cap G|-|O\cap G\cap A|=25-15=10$.

For B), the number of people that bought a juice other than apple, orange or grape is $500-|O\cup A\cup G|$. And, by the inclusion-exclusion formula,

$$
\begin{aligned}
|O\cup A\cup G|&=|O|+|A|+|G|-|O\cap A|-|O\cap G|-|A\cap G|+|O\cap A\cap G|\\
&=400+110+50-75-25-30+15\\
&=445.
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus, the answer for B) is $500-445=55$.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by linear equations.

Note $x^{i}$ the amount of people that bought only the juice $i$ ($i=A$ for apple, $i=G$ for grape, $i=O$ for orange), $x^{i,j}=x^{j,i}$ when they bought two kinds of juices and $x^{A,O,G}$ when they bought every kind.

$x^O+x^{O,A}+x^{O,G}+x^{A,O,G}=400$

$x^A+x^{A,O}+x^{A,G}+x^{A,O,G}=110$

$x^G+x^{G,O}+x^{G,A}+x^{A,O,G}=50$

$x^{O,A}+x^{A,O,G}=75 $

$x^{O,G}+x^{A,O,G}=25$

$x^{A,G}+x^{A,O,G}=30$

$x^{O,A,G}=15$

$x^O+x^A+x^G+x^{O,A}+x^{O,G}+x^{A,O,G}=500$

I let you finish